# Make ffmpeg read subtitles as stream

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, .srt

I have a stream (rtmp) and I would like to generate some subtitles for it(based on what's happened on stream). I can generate it like a pipe, or some other way. I use script like this:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 20); do echo "
00:00:$i,000 --> 00:00:$i,999
caption $i
"; sleep 1; done | ffmpeg -nostdin \
-i "rtmp://domain.com/streamName live=1" \
-f srt -re -i - \
-c copy \
-c:s text \
-flush_packets 1 -f flv rtmp://output
```

the first part of a script is create a pipe with actually subs, pipe it to ffmpeg, and ffmpeg should merge subs with the stream.
The point is that ffmpeg starts generating output only after the pipe is closed, and subtitles generation is ended.
Is it possible to force ffmpeg start generation of output as soon as first lines in pipe appears?

Comment: Works here when I pipe an existing SRT file.

Comment: @Gyan because existing SRT could be read to the end, while I actually need to generate it on the fly

Comment: With `-re` flag, ffmpeg reads the input in real time - it delays reading the next packet until time elapsed is equal to media timestamp

Comment: @Gyan without `-re` it still wait until srt `EOF` before output starts. The difference is that with `-re` output is thrown like a realtime stream, while without it - all at once,

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Need to do this as well